# What is the correct format of the body in phpmailer?

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm sending custom HTML mails with phpmailer. But i can't find in the docs if you need html, head or body tags in the body of the mail. Which i think is important for for example font-imports in the head.

So what is the right way (A,B,C)?

And as a side question: What is the best and most reliable way to import fonts (kind of dependent on the first question)?

A:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "hello";
$mail->Body    = '
<style>
  @font-face {font-family: "...";} 
</style>
<div style="...">
  content
</div>
';
$mail->AltBody = "no support for html content";
```

B:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "hello";
$mail->Body    = '
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {font-family: "...";} 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="...">
        content
    </div>
</body>
';
$mail->AltBody = "no support for html content";
```

C:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "hello";
$mail->Body    = '
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face {font-family: "...";} 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="...">
            content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
';
$mail->AltBody = "no support for html content";
```

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with PHPMailer, but rather about HTML emails in general. PHPMailer is just a mailer that sends what you tell it to. There are many many resources out there about best practices regarding building HTML emails.

Comment: Tanks - i was thinking if phpmailer maybe wraps the $mail->Body in a html/body tag. But you are generally right.

Comment: PHPMailer doesn't do that. All the `isHTML()` does is setting the correct content type for that part of the email so the clients know how to present it.